# How to connect gaze input cursor with Bluetooth controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, controller, virtual-reality, google-vr

Hi I developed an app vr gaze app by watching tutorial.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YTVsLnK-XU) where when the reticle(VR gaze cursor) is clicked the cube will move upward.each time I click the cube it will move upward.actually the project works in unity.but after making it as an app. I used Bluetooth controller.but the gaze cursor is not selected by the controller. It's not working.even after clicking also it's not moving upward .Please help!
ma unity version is 5.5.2 the googlevr sdk version is v1.0.0
the code i used is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveStoolUp : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void movestoolupward()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the controller code? The code that gets input from the bluetooth controller...Without it we really can't tell what's going on. You should also tell us where you are running this? Editor? Build?

Comment: actually it works well  on editor.i developed into an android app and deployed it in ma mobile. if i connected ma mobile and bluetooth contoller the gaze cursor is not connected with the bluetooth controller. i din use any controller code. in that tutorial its not given how to add it ?please do reply

Comment: @Programmer   
hi i have developed the app by watching this tutorial ( google.co.in/… ) the controller i used is vr box's bluetooth controller. ma unity version is 5.5.2 the googlevr sdk i used is v1.0.0

Comment: @Programmer  how to make this app work with the bluetooth controller?? i have a gaze cursor used in this app. the bluetooth controller must detect the gaze cursor and if the button is pressed down the gazecursor must make the cube move upward